# How to make sure saving ParseObject and ParseRelation using saveEventually()

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have started using Parse library recently for Android app. I want to store user contacts using saveEventually and then use the ParseRelation to relate the same to user. As there are multiple contacts mapped to user, I am using below code to handle my save functionality.

```
ParseRelation relation = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation(relationshipName);

for(int entityIndex = 0; entityIndex < entities.length;entityIndex++) { 
... 
  entity[entityIndex].saveEventually(); relation.add(entity[entityIndex]); 
...    
}

ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();
```

Here I am using saveEventually() for each valid entity (ParseObject) and then adding the same to relation. Later once all the objects are added to ParseRelation, at the end I am calling saveEventually() for ParseUser to store all the relationship to Parse.

Is this approach right? I am getting below exception at relation.add(entity[entityIndex]);

**All objects in a relation must have object ids.**

It seems this suggest some network connectivity issue and ParseRelation is not getting unique objectId for each ParseObject, but I was assuming that this saveEventuall() will handle this scenario well with ParseRelation

Kindly suggest. I am using Parse library version 1.1.11

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any object that's added to a ParseRelation *must* be saved first. The saveEventually call is non-blocking, so it's unlikely that the object will already have been saved by the time execution reaches the very next line when it's added to a ParseRelation.

Since you need to make sure the object is saved first, you should use saveInBackground instead of saveEventually. Then make sure to add the saved object to the relation from inside saveInBackground's SaveCallback. This will ensure that the object has been saved before being added to the relation.

Comment: Thanks Hector. Sorry for replying late. I understand what you are suggesting. But I don't want that operation to be network dependent (when user saves the data). I want that whenever network connectivity is there, the data gets stored else it remain locally as done by saveEventually(). As per your suggestion, its not possible with ParseRelation. Then, is there any way I can avoid network dependency and still persist related objects locally if not network there? There will always be some relation betn the objects and this restriction make saveEventuall() not usable at most of the place.

Comment: Thanks Hector. I got your point. I should be using saveEventually(SaveCallback callback) to achieve what I am trying to do. As this will make sure all the objects are stored locally till the network is not available and once network connectivity is there save the object and call the callback to store relationship.